# Spring Security OpenID - UserDetailsService, AuthenticationUserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openid

Trying to understand what's the correct way of implementing OpenID authentication with Spring Security.

```
public class OpenIDUserDetailsService implements 
  UserDetailsService, 
  AuthenticationUserDetailsService {

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String openId) throws
    UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    // I either want user email here
    // or immediately delegate the request to loadUserDetails

  }

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserDetails(Authentication token) throws
    UsernameNotFoundException {

    // This never gets called if I throw from loadUserByUsername()

  }

  private MyCustomUserDetails registerUser(String openId, String email) {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm considering the scenario when user is not yet registered within my application. To register the user, I need to know its OpenID and email.

When OpenID provider redirects the user back to my application, `loadUserByUsername()` is called, but in this case I'm only aware about user's OpenID. So, I'm throwing `UsernameNotFoundException` and then `loadUserDetails()` never gets called, so I can't register user.

What's the common solution here? What if I return something like `FakePartialUserDetails` from `loadUserByUsername()` and then, when `loadUserDetails()` is called, I register the user and  then return the real `MyCustomUserDetails`?

I'm using Spring Security 3.0.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's funny, but managed to resolve it by moving to **Spring Security 3.1.0.RELEASE**.

**For the same scenario, behavior is absolutely different** - `loadUserByUsername()` is not called and `loadUserDetails()` is called instead.

Comment: This is not correct. In 3.1, OpenIDAuthenticationProvider has setters for both UserDetailsService and AuthenticationUserDetailsService and calls either loadUserByUsername or loadUserDetails depending on which setter is used. In 3.0.7, there was no setter for AuthenticationUserDetailsService and so it always used loadUserByUsername.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same situation by implementing

```
AuthenticationUserDetailsService<OpenIDAuthenticationToken>
```

in my UserDetailsService.

```
public class OpenIdUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService,
    AuthenticationUserDetailsService<OpenIDAuthenticationToken> {

@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier(value = "jdbcUserDetailsService")
private UserDetailsService localUserDetailsService;

/**
 * @return the localUserDetailsService
 */
public UserDetailsService getLocalUserDetailsService() {
    return localUserDetailsService;
}

/**
 * @param localUserDetailsService
 *            the localUserDetailsService to set
 */
public void setLocalUserDetailsService(
        UserDetailsService localUserDetailsService) {
    this.localUserDetailsService = localUserDetailsService;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserDetails(OpenIDAuthenticationToken token)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    String email = getEmail(token);
    return loadUserByUsername(email);
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return localUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
}

private String getEmail(OpenIDAuthenticationToken token) {
    for (OpenIDAttribute attribute : token.getAttributes()) {
        if (attribute.getName().equals("email")) {
            return attribute.getValues().get(0);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

Just make sure to use above service as the UserDetailsService while configuring openid-form. Also, configure attribute exchange for 'email' attribute while configuring openid.
The email returned after successfull authentication can then be fetched from 'OpenIDAuthenticationToken' which eventually gets passed as paramter to loadUserByUsername function.

If you have user registered with that email, authentication is complete. Else you can suggest user to get registered by that email or show login failure page.

Comment: Actual reason for OP is answered by Ritesh (comment for accepted answer!)